# How to transition away from dog walker?

Tags: dogs, behavior, training

**Background**

So currently we have a puppy that is approaching 6 months of age and is a Miniature Golden Doodle. Both my wife and myself work jobs where we will be both be gone for about 8 hours a day so we have had a dog walker come half way during the day to let our puppy out for half an hour.

Currently she does wonderfully in terms of potty training. She has never had an accident in her crate and hasn't had an accident in the house in a long time.

**Problem**

So obviously a dog walker costs money so what is a good way to transition away from a dog walker and at what age? (i.e. do task A when puppy is 6 months old, task B when puppy is 8 months old, etc.) We definitely don't want to ruin our success with potty training at all or create any separation anxiety if she has to be alone for a long time such as 8 hours.  Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: As your dog gets older, they can hold their business for a long time. I have left my dog alone for 12 hours or a little longer at times and no accident. Once trained they know to hold it until let out. Unless they have to pee obviously. As far as separation anxiety, I think you are over thinking this. If your dog is fine with no one around for hours, then 8 hours is not an issue. Don't give too much water when you leave in the morning

Comment: @Huangism At what age was your dog when you left them alone for a long period of time like 12 hours? Our dog free feeds so the control of what goes in is a little more free than with assigned feeding times but I supposed they eventually learn for themselves too

Comment: Well, we started that very early due to work but  work from home 2-3 days a week. I left the dog alone for a work day a few days after I took it home so started from 9 weeks. We had a crate + pen so the pup would never pee in her crate. Somewhere between 7-9 month, no more peeing at home

Answer (score 1):

When working full time with a young dog at home and trying to avoid the expense of dog walkers, it becomes necessary to tire the dog before you leave for work.  I know, it can be exhausting, but prevents behavioral problems.  I learned the hard way when my dogs ate their entire dog house.  So, I spent 30 minutes in the morning and 30 minutes at days end running the dogs on a leash.  You will reap the benefits as the dogs will not adopt bad habits from excess energy.  I've raised labs for most of my adult life.